# How to change the text of the running title?

Tags: header-footer

I would like to change the text (not the style) of the running header for my supplementary section.

In the following MWE, the line marked "INVALID" is the functionality I'm hoping to find.

Thanks in advance ...

```
\documentclass[utf8]{FrontiersinHarvard}

\def\firstAuthorLast{Dodgson}
\def\Authors{C.L. Dodgson}
\def\Address{Oxford}
\def\corrAuthor{Par 7}
\def\corrEmail{noreply@email.com}

\def\MyShortTitle{Dew Point}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\firstpage{1}

\title[\MyShortTitle]{When Steam Cools}
\author[\firstAuthorLast ]{\Authors}
\address{}
\correspondance{}
\extraAuth{}
\maketitle

\section{Main}
'Twas brillig

\clearpage
\section*{Supplementary Tables}
\renewcommand{@title}{\MyShortTitle - Supplementary} %% INVALID
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
and the big Mississippi and the town Honolulu

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we (the community) find `FrontiersinHarvard.cls`?

Comment: Your `\renewcommand` doesn't work. You could use `\makeatletter\renewcommand\@title{<stuff>}\makeatother` instead.

Comment: @Werner https://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers_LaTeX_Templates.zip

Comment: @Skillmon, I'm sorry but that common approach is ignored in this case.

Comment: Off-topic, but possibly of interest in this content: If the book is printed to paper, using print-on-demand, then it is a bad idea to change the running header (even if it should be changed!). Some POD services reject books with changing headers, as part of the manufacturing workflow. If in doubt, ask them.

Comment: @rallg It's not a book. The journal article was accepted with the fix below.

Comment: @Hermitian OK, but sometimes folks find these questions by search, with a different situation.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any additional packages, you can change the right mark before the supplementary section.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[utf8]{FrontiersinHarvard}

\def\firstAuthorLast{Dodgson}
\def\Authors{C.L. Dodgson}
\def\Address{Oxford}
\def\corrAuthor{Par 7}
\def\corrEmail{noreply@email.com}

\def\MyShortTitle{Dew Point}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \onecolumn
    \firstpage{1}
    
    \title[\MyShortTitle]{When Steam Cools}
    \author[\firstAuthorLast ]{\Authors}
    \address{}
    \correspondance{}
    \extraAuth{}
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Main}
    'Twas brillig
    
    \kant[1-6] % to make tow pages

    \clearpage
    
    \markright{\MyShortTitle--Supplementary} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \section*{Supplementary Tables}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{S-\arabic{page}}
    and the big Mississippi and the town Honolulu

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thank you very much.